# Can't install PyBluez

Tags: python, pip

I have a PI3.  I've tried installing pybluez with:

```
pip install pybluez
```

and

```
pip3 install pybluez
```

Both fail with:

```
Command /usr/bin/python3 -c "import setuptools, 
  tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip-build-2yikecdn/pybluez/setup.py';
  exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)
  (__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" 
  install
  --record /tmp/pip-sx4_w49r-record/install-record.txt
  --single-version-externally-managed --compile

failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-2yikecdn/pybluez

Storing debug log for failure in /home/pi/.pip/pip.log
```

I really need to use pybluez.  Can anyone help me out?

Thanks a million!

Comment: What does the log say?

Comment: What does `sudo pip3 install pybluez` do? What's in /home/pi/.pip/pip.log?

Answer (score 17):

Finally found an answer to the issue.  Need to do the following to get pybluez installed on Raspberry Pi 3

```
sudo apt-get install libbluetooth-dev
sudo apt-get install python-dev
sudo pip install PyBluez
```

The first two install the appropriate header files that are missing.

Comment: Please accept your own answer with a click on the tick on its left side. Only this will finish the question and it will not pop up again year for year.